# Is there a version of Scala with only syntax (no Predef etc)

Tags: scala, sbt

This question is one of interest. I don't have a specific problem to solve.

Scala defines a lot of what naively appears to be syntax via flexible language constructs. For example, `List` is not a built-in, the arrows in `Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2)` are defined using an implicit conversion of `Any` to a class with a `->` method returning a `Tuple2`.

Is there a stripped-down version of Scala that doesn't have any of this stuff included, i.e. all the syntax, but none of the predefined constructs?

Comment: Use scalac flags: `-Yno-predef` or `-Yno-imports`.

Comment: Or more generally, check out the `scalac -Y` flags.

Comment: There's a nice list of recommended scalac flags here: http://tpolecat.github.io/2017/04/25/scalac-flags.html

Comment: If you want to define the imports own your own in one file and then import it, it's a *custom Predef*. I wrote a blog post about it a while ago: https://kubuszok.com/2017/adventures-with-custom-predef/